# Using numerical equivalent of IPC_CREAT in shmget() C

Tags: c, permissions, ipc, shared-memory

I was learning how to create a shared memory using `shmget()`. Up to this point, all the examples that I found use `IPC_CREAT | <shm_perm>` format for the flag (or something similar). When I checked my `bits/ipc.h` content `IPC_CREAT` was defined to be `01000`.

I tried to create a shared memory with permission of `0600`. First I used the formal method = >`IPC_CREAT | 0600`, it worked. Then instead of bitwise OR-ing the two, just used `01600`, I could not observe any difference in the result, but not sure if it applies for all cases as I am new to C programming.

This might be something trivial, but I wonder why it is better to use the OR-ing method rather than just concatenating `01` with a required permission type (I found the latter method easier to remember and type).

- **Is there special feature that the formal method has and the latter lacks (maybe related with OS)?**
- **Is it safe to use the latter method if I am more comfortable with that one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it by doing `printf("%o\n", IPC_CREAT | 0600)`. It will print 1600 if IPC_CREAT is 01000 which is in my system.

But here is the problem:
Macros can vary system to system so you shouldn't rely on the value in your system.

And using magic numbers makes code less readable for other people and for you. I can understand what `IPC_CREAT | 0600` means when I see it -rwx octals are well known- but I probably would say "what the heck is 01600" if I see it. And you too probably wouldn't remember what was it after a while.

Answer (score 3):

The former method is the correct way to call the function, because it makes your code system independent.  Just because IPC_CREAT is defined as `01000` on your development system, it does not mean it will be the same elsewhere (although it will more likely than not remain the same for the major version of the same operating system).

It's better to use to become comfortable with the *first one*, as a matter of fact, it makes for easier maintenance of your software.

I would even recommend going as far as replacing `0600` with proper constants, as in:

`shm_open(..., O_RDWR|IPC_CREAT);`